# Json data not rendering my html grid table

Tags: html, json, angular, observable, rendering

I can't able to render my html grid table in angular using json data that is from mysql database.Please someone help me.

[Output of the angular code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zynZI.jpg)

```
    export class UserlistComponent implements OnInit {

  users: Observable<User[]>;

  constructor(private _service:NgserviceService, private _route:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reloadData();
  }

  reloadData(){
    this.users = this._service.getUserList();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please atach part of your code

Comment: It seems you have there array of arrays, not array of object therefore `let user` is array not object

Comment: make sure your collection 'users' is observable and check for errors in the browser console

Comment: i will add my component.ts code.Guide me @ArmenStepanyan

Comment: my users is observable only and my browser console doens't throwing any errors @MujassirNasir

Comment: @sathishkumar your output seems to be csv kind (array of array) not the json so to get the email you need to use {{user[1]}} for firstname {{user[2]}}

Comment: {{user[1]}} for firstname instead of {{user.firstname}} right? @MujassirNasir

Comment: right {{user[1]}} for email instead of {{user.email}} and {{user[2]}} for firstname instead of {{user.firstname}}

Comment: @sathishkumar you can mark the answer to helper others find the correct answer. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output seems to be CSV kind (array of an array) not the JSON. So, you need to use `{{user[1]}}` for email instead of `{{user.email}}` and `{{user[2]}}` for firstname instead of `{{user.firstname}}`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you receive an array and not an object. You could simply map the received data and keep the rest.

```
reloadData() {
    this.users = this._service.getUserList().pipe(
      map(arrayUsers => arrayUsers.map(arrayUser => ({
        id: arrayUser[0],
        email: arrayUser[1],
        firstname: arrayUser[2],
        lastname: arrayUser[3],
      })))
    );
  }
```